# Delete data in Room using INNER JOIN?

Tags: android, inner-join, android-room

I try to delete data from room database using INNER JOIN.
My code does not build. Below is the error.

[image]

How to delete data using INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite does't accept this syntax , because it is different from SQL Server. 
so the best solution is 
 `DELETE FROM waybills wb WHERE status IN (SELECT type FROM timestamps WHERE timestamp = 23)`

Answer (score 1):

What about following query :

```
DELETE FROM waybills WHERE status IN (SELECT type FROM timestamps WHERE timestamp = 23)
```

Comment: Is not it possible to do the deletion using inner join?